# What are the prefixes associated with Excel functions in the xml files which excel writes

Tags: excel, xml, excel-2010, openxml

Excel has a large variety of functions which we can use in cells. When we see the XML files for the excel, we find the formula is set in the <f> (formula tag) inside <c> (cell tag).

Some of these functions have prefixes applied to them such as _xlfn., _xlws. E.g: SEC(), SWITCH(), SORT()

Some of these functions have attributes which have a prefix such as _xlpm. E.g: LET(), LAMBDA()

Is there a list of all prefixes or a documentation which defines the use of these prefixes and when they will be present. PS i already know the use of these prefixes i have mentioned. I would like to know any/all other prefixes and their uses.

I have gone through a lot of documents and found that _xlfn. is used for Future functions (Backward Compatibility). _xlws. represents web service based functions. Not sure what that is but it appears with SORT(). _xlpm. represents parameter and comes with the Parameters of LET() and LAMBDA().

If possible, i would like to know the exact use of _xlws., and _xlop. and other prefixes similar to these.

Also, it would be really helpful if you could link some documentation which you referred.

Comment: I've found no such documentation; however, from Microsoft's Open Specifications of FTAB (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xlsb/90a52fcb-ce63-497f-a3d3-173c42d82242) and by examining names in one of my workbooks, I've learned that `_xlpm` designates parameters used in `LAMBDA` definitions, and `_xlop` designates optional parameters.

Comment: "_xlws. represents web service based functions. Not sure what that is " ... I *believe but it's only a guess* that web-service-based functions are only available in versions that connect through the web (e.g., O365 flavors).